# JUnit Result Aggregation

Tags: junit, reporting

I'm familiar with aggregating junit test results within a single build, but are there any tools that let you aggregate results across different builds?

I'd like to discover which tests failed most frequently, though not necessarily continuously.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for a simple shell script (grep+sed / awk), gathering output from distinct text/xml files.
Alternatively, you could define a custom formatter which appends failure logs to a single file.

Answer (score 0):

Maven has aggregation support, but that requires switching the whole build to maven.